# PyPDF2 prints hundreds of blank pages on append

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, pypdf

It worked the first time now PyPDF2 returns the second part of PDF append (cv_select) as hundreds of blank pages?

I tried to turn the working script into an 'exe' using pyinstaller... when tried script as exe blank pages for the appended PDF. Then uninstalled pyinstaller and no change to issue... appended PDF being printed as blanks in the hundreds??

When using the same folder to choose PDF's to append the problem disappears? When choosing different folder path the second PDF is printed hundreds of times as a blank page?? Using tkinter to select folders and files.

Any help would be much appreciated

```
def open_coverletter_folder():
    global coverletter_directory
    coverletter_directory = askdirectory() 
    print(coverletter_directory)

def open_cvselect():
    global cv_select
    cv_select = askopenfilename()    
    print(cv_select)

def pdfoutputfolder():
    global output_directory
    output_directory = askdirectory()
    print(output_directory)

def globconvert():   
    if coverletter_directory and cv_select and output_directory:        
        pdf_file = [f for f in os.listdir(coverletter_directory) if f.endswith(".pdf")]      
        pdf_file.append(cv_select)
        combine = PdfFileMerger()
        for pdf in pdf_file:
            srcfile = os.path.join(coverletter_directory, pdf)
            outfile = os.path.join(output_directory, pdf)
            print(f"{srcfile} --> {outfile}")
            combine = PdfFileMerger()
            combine.append(srcfile)
            combine.append(cv_select)
            combine.write(outfile)
            combine.close()
        messagebox.showinfo("PDF Merge", f"Total {len(pdf_file)} PDF files created")
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("PDF Merge", "Please select covers folder, CV and output folder")
```

Comment: `pdf_file.append(cv_select)` (it is the cause of those blank pages) and `combine = PdfFileMerger()` before `for pdf in pdf_file:` should be removed.

Comment: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: I have tried to remove the other instead but get the same result